# dotnet run hangs / is stuck

Tags: c#, .net, kestrel-http-server, .net-7.0

A [razor webapp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new-sdk-templates#web-options) can no longer be started on my machine.

The build command `dotnet build` works as expected but `dotnet run` is stuck after the first warnings.

```
C:\dev\mywebapp>dotnet run
Building...
C:\dev\mywebapp\Pages\Admin\Orders\TraderOrderList.cshtml.cs(101,17): 
     warning CS0219: The variable 'orderId' is assigned but its value is 
                     never used [C:\dev\mywebapp\MyWebApp.csproj]

C:\dev\mywebapp\Pages\Index.cshtml.cs(23,24): 
     warning CS0414: The field 'IndexModel._currentAd' is assigned but its value is
                     never used [C:\dev\mywebapp\MyWebApp.csproj]

--- after here it is stuck no more output and i stopped it after about 3 minutes
```

#### What have i tried?

- I created a new project `c:\dev\webtemp>dotnet new webapp -o HelloWebApp`
- And ran it with `c:\dev\webtemp\HelloWebApp>dotnet run`. So this works as expected.

I searched for other questions on stackoverflow but they do not have the same problem.

#### Question

- How can the issue be narrowed down?
- Where is a log file for the dotnet run command?

#### dotnet --info

Below certain paths were replaced for brevity

| name used | path |
| --- | --- |
| `<path-to-AspNetCore.App>` | `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` |
| `<path-shared-NETCore>` | `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App` |
| `<path-shared-WindowsDesktop>` | `C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App` |

Running `dotnet --info` returns

```
c:\dev\webtemp\HelloWebApp>dotnet --info
.NET SDK:   Version:   7.0.100 Commit:    e12b7af219

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows  OS Version:  10.0.19042
 OS Platform: Windows RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100\

Host: Version:  7.0.0   Architecture: x64  Commit:       d099f075e4

.NET SDKs installed:
  3.1.120 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]    3.1.426 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.408 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  6.0.113 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  7.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.20 [<path-to-AspNetCore.App>]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.32 [<path-to-AspNetCore.App>]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.17 [<path-to-AspNetCore.App>]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.13 [<path-to-AspNetCore.App>]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.0 [<path-to-AspNetCore.App>]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.20 [<path-shared-NETCore>]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.32 [<path-shared-NETCore>]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.17 [<path-shared-NETCore>]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.13 [<path-shared-NETCore>]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.0 [<path-shared-NETCore>]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.20 [<path-shared-WindowsDesktop>]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.32 [<path-shared-WindowsDesktop>]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.17 [<path-shared-WindowsDesktop>]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.13 [<path-shared-WindowsDesktop>]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.0 [<path-shared-WindowsDesktop>]

Other architectures found:
  x86   [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet]
    registered at [HKLM\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x86\InstallLocation]

Environment variables:   Not set
global.json file:        Not found
```

#### Update - using another branch returns 404

I did change the branch and `dotnet run` reached the part where localhost is started.

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:7178 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5057 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down. info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\dev\mywebapp\
```

But it returns [http 404](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#client_error_responses)

> #### 404 Not Found
>
> The server cannot find the requested resource. ...
>
> Servers may also send this response instead of 403 Forbidden to
> hide the existence of a resource from an unauthorized client.

I tried a few different urls but every razor page failed (404). Only the static html page under wwwroot works (200)

| path | url | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `C:\...\wwwroot\index.htm` | `https://localhost:7178/index.htm` | 200 |
| `C:\...\Pages\info.cshtml` | `https://localhost:7178/privacy` | 404 |
| as above | `https://localhost:7178/privacy.cshtml` | 404 |
| as above | `https://localhost:7178/Pages/privacy/` | 404 |
| as above | `https://localhost:7178/Pages/privacy.cshtml` | 404 |

Here you can see a screenshot of devtools

[image: localhost_redirect_and_404]

Comment: _How can the issue be narrowed down?_ - Checkout the last Commit of which you _know_ it worked. Then work your way forward to the first one where it doesn't. Then that changeset contains your culprit.

Comment: I did switch the branch and `dotnet run` works partly. It reaches localhost but it returns 404 (see update above).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem a few days ago.

In my case, I was using NLog for logging. I had put in all the necessary code and configuration but forgot to create the `nlog.config` file in my project. The lack of an `nlog.config` file was causing the application to hang.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I ran into this problem too, turned out I altered my logging levels (appsettings.json) so information messages were no longer displayed. Looked like it kept building but it was actually running but didn't show on what port is was running.

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```